# Replacing a PDF file for another in VS solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, updates

I have a PDF document in the downloads folder of my solution that needs updating.  I have the new file to replace it, but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

This seems like it should be straight forward, however I am not seeing an obvious solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: System.io.file.Copy(SourceFile, DestFile, Overwrite)

Comment: Do you just want to replace the file from Windows File Explorer?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I have found the solution though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off remember to not be running the application...silly me.
Check the file out.  Then click on the folder and select Add-->Existing Item.

Like I said, it should be fairly straight forward. Between running the application and not checking out the file first I stumbled around.